# Finding the k-largest clusters in dbscan result

Tags: r, dbscan

I have a dataframe *df*, consists of 2 columns: *x* and *y* coordinates.
Each row refers to a point.
I feed it into *dbscan* function to obtain the clusters of the points in *df*.

```
library("fpc")
db = fpc::dbscan(df, eps = 0.08, MinPts = 4)
plot(db, df, main = "DBSCAN", frame = FALSE)
```

By using *print(db)*, I can see the result returned by *dbscan*.

```
> print(db)
dbscan Pts=13131 MinPts=4 eps=0.08
         0    1    2  3  4   5  6 7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
border 401   38   55  5  2   3  0 0  0  8  0  6  1  3  1  3  3  2  1  2  4  3
seed     0 2634 8186 35 24 561 99 7 22 26  5 75 17  9  9 54  1  2 74 21  3 15
total  401 2672 8241 40 26 564 99 7 22 34  5 81 18 12 10 57  4  4 75 23  7 18
       22 23 24 25 26 27 28  29 30 31 32 33  34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44
border  4  1  2  6  2  1  3   7  2  1  2  3  11  1  3  1  3  2  5  5  1  4  3
seed   14  9  4 48  2  4 38 111  5 11  5 14 111  6  1  5  1  8  3 15 10 15  6
total  18 10  6 54  4  5 41 118  7 12  7 17 122  7  4  6  4 10  8 20 11 19  9
       45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68
border  2  4  2  1  3  2  1  1  3  1  0  2  2  3  0  3  3  3  3  0  0  2  3  1
seed   15  2  9 11  4  8 12  4  6  8  7  7  3  3  4  3  3  4  2  9  4  2  1  4
total  17  6 11 12  7 10 13  5  9  9  7  9  5  6  4  6  6  7  5  9  4  4  4  5
       69 70 71
border  3  3  3
seed    1  1  1
total   4  4  4
```

From the above summary, I can see cluster 2 consists of 8186 seed points (core points), cluster 1 consists of 2634 seed points and cluster 5 consists of 561 points.

I define the largest cluster as the one contains the largest amount of seed points. So, in this case, the largest cluster is cluster 2. And the 1st, 2nd, 3th largest clusters are 2, 1 and 5.

**Are they any direct way to return the rows (points) in the largest cluster or the k-largest cluster in general?**

I can do it in an indirect way.

1. I can obtain the assigned cluster number of each point by
   *db$cluster*.
2. Hence, I can create a new dataframe *df2* with *db$cluster* as the
   new additional column besides the original *x* column and *y*
   column.
3. Then, I can aggregate the *df2* according to the cluster numbers in
   the third column and find the number of points in each cluster.
4. After that, I can find the k-largest groups, which are 2, 1 and 5
   again.
5. Finally, I can select the rows in *df2* with third column value equals to 2 to return the points in the largest cluster.

But the above approach re-computes many known results as stated in the summary of *print(db)*.

Comment: Create your own function containing the 5 "indirect" steps you outlined. The input arguments to this function can be the results of the dbscan function, the data, and k. The output of your function is your desired data frame containing the rows corresponding to the kth largest cluster. Voila, you now have a direct method of obtaining what you want. :)

Comment: I think I should make use of the result of the summary listed in print(db) instead of computing everything again from the sketch. But the point is, I don't know how to extract information from the summary. >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dbscan` function doesn't appear to retain the data.

```
library(fpc)
set.seed(665544)
n <- 600
df <- data.frame(x=runif(10, 0, 10)+rnorm(n, sd=0.2), y=runif(10, 0, 10)+rnorm(n,sd=0.2))
(dbs <- dbscan(df, 0.2))
#dbscan Pts=600 MinPts=5 eps=0.2
#        0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
#border 28  4  4  8  5  3  3  4  3  4  6  4
#seed    0 50 53 51 52 51 54 54 54 53 51  1
#total  28 54 57 59 57 54 57 58 57 57 57  5

attributes(dbs)
#$names
#[1] "cluster" "eps"     "MinPts"  "isseed" 

#$class
#[1] "dbscan"
```

Your indirect steps are not that indirect (only two lines needed), and these commands won't recalculate the clusters. So just run those commands, or put them in a function and then call the function in one command.

```
cluster_k <- function(dbs, data, k){
  kth <- names(rev(sort(table(dbs$cluster)))[k])
  data[dbs$cluster == kth,]
}

cluster_k(dbs=dbs, data=df, k=1)
##            x        y
## 3   6.580695 8.715245
## 13  6.704379 8.528486
## 23  6.809558 8.160721
## 33  6.375842 8.756433
## 43  6.603195 8.640206
## 53  6.728533 8.425067

## a data frame with 59 rows
```

Comment: Amazing, Thanks! Since I am new to R, I still hardly believe you can implement the 5 steps into an elegant function with simply 2 lines. The syntax most surprises me is "data[dbs$cluster == kth,]". I think it means (1) add dbs$cluster as a new column data$cluster in data, (2) Pick the rows with data$cluster== kth and (3) remove data$cluster from data.

Comment: The `dbscan` function returns the cluster vector the same length as the data but also in the same order as the data. This is crucial. It's really what defines R and what makes the program so attractive. So we can use that vector, or a logical vector in this case, to index the rows of the data. :)

Comment: In fact, just one line is possible, but often it's better to make the code more readable. Also easier to debug or modify.

Comment: May I also see the one line version? I quite like this kind of concise writing style.

Comment: You just replace `kth` in the second line with the expression for `kth` from the first line. `data[dbs$cluster==names(rev(sort(table(dbs$cluster)))[k],]`. Kind of ugly though.